# Show that there are no analytic functions $f=u+iv$ with $u(x,y)=x^2+y^2$.

Tags: complex-analysis

I was trying to prove this using the method of contradiction, so,

I assumed on the contrary that their is such an analytic function $f=u+iv$ with $u(x,y)=x^2+y^2$.

Now since $f$ is analytic therefore it must be differentiable and must satisfy the Cauchy Riemann equations $u_x$=$v_y$ and $u_y$=$-v_x$.

So i started off by calculating $u_x=2x$ and using the first CR equation concluded that $v_y=2x$

=>$v=2xy+h(x)$

Similarly using the second CR equation i found out that $v_x =-2y$

=>$v=-2xy+g(y)$

=>$2xy+h(x)=-2xy+g(y)$

=>$4xy+h(x)=g(y)$

I am stuck at this point and can't figure out how to proceed further to get a contradiction.Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you try to use the Cauchy Riemann equation for polar coordinates ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using your last relation $$4xy +h(x) = g(y)$$
with $x=0$, you obtain that $g(y) = h(0)$ is a constant. Similarly, $h(x) = g(0)$ is constant. So you have shown that $v(x,y) = 2xy + h(0)$ and $v(x,y) = - 2xy + g(0)$, which is impossible.

Answer (score 6):

An analytic function has real (and imaginary) part a harmonic function. That is, sum of second partials is zero. But for $x^2+y^2$ this sum is $4$.

Note I mean the two pure partials, not the mixed partial, in the sum. So $u_{xx}+u_{yy}=0.$

Answer (score 2):

$$u_r = \frac{v_{\theta}}{r} \mbox{ and } v_{r} = \frac{- u_{\theta}}{r}.$$

$ u = r \implies v_{\theta} = r, \mbox{ and } v_{r} = 0 $, so we have $v = r\theta + f(r)$  and $v = g(\theta)$ individually from each equation which is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Every analytic function should have harmonic components. That is if  $f(x,y) = u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$, then
$\bigtriangledown^2 u = 0 $
Here the harmonicity in $u(x,y)$ is violated

Comment: This is not an answer to the OP's question, which was specifically about where he went wrong in his calculations. It has already been answered by someone. You may post this as a comment (once you have enough reputaton).